# How to orchestrate multiple microservices on local env?

Tags: docker, development-environment, microservices, orchestration

at the moment of speaking I have a bunch of services running each one on its own container
Every repo of code has its own Docker file and docker compose file in order to bring up the service on my local dev-machine

Everything is fine and I'm able o access each service at

http://localhost:[service mapped/exposed port]

Problem is that services are augmenting and I'm thinking that could be a better idea to have everything in a local private network, where each service 's container has its own IP address.

Is this a better approach to orchestrate containers locally?

Where should I start from to make up my mind?

Comment: What don't you like about `docker compose` as an orchestrator?

Comment: Not that... I 'm not liking to use ports to map each container on host... instead of having each one its own IP on a private network. Are you suggesting to use a unique docker compose file to orchestrate multiple services/containers? now every service has it's own Dockerfile/s and docker-compose.

Comment: yes. I use `compose` with one dicker-compose.yml to create a private network in which the MSs can *see* eachother without exposing their ports

Comment: I can Imagine there's a way to do it. Where should I start from? And also, how do you access each service (e.g. via Http) from you host machine in order to manage them (e.g. access service management UI)?

Comment: You start at the docker-compose docs website: https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/

Comment: If you need to access each microservice individually from the outside (of the private network) then you need to expose a port for each.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you would describe your entire setup in one or multiple docker compose files. See the documentation for [details](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/).

Concerning networking and linking your services:
Docker compose supports [networking](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/). You can define networks and all services which are in the same network can access each other with their serviceName and internal port (as the application knows it). E.g : http://mySuperService:3001

In case you want multiple replicas of your services or maybe multiple machines you would need to look into orchestrators such as docker swarm (easyest to start with) or Kubernetes or others.